# Gravity map GOCE

Tags: satellite, esa, gravity-model

I'm trying to produce a gravity map out of some GOCE ([Gravity field and steady-state Ocean Circulation Explorer](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/GOCE)) data I downloaded from ESA's (European Space Agency) GOCE archive. I'm trying to follow a tutorial provided with the GUT(GOCE User Toolbox) software. But I can't even get GUT to open the data.

What I am after is a relatively high quality gravity map that shows the localised density in mineralisation in parts of Greenland. I'm looking for something like this magnetic map.

[image]

Do you know anywhere I can retrieve this type of map or is GOCE the only way to go? At this point I'd love to just get a WMS link I can hook up to in QGIS, or something like it that can be used.

In that case how do I open the .HDR or .DBL file that comes out of a GOCE download?

Comment: When I googled GOCE to find out what it stands for, I discovered that it also means "joy" in Spanish.

Comment: :D Random. 
It's becoming more evident that the spatial resolution on this stuff is too low after all. So it might be a wild goose chase.

Comment: If the data you currently have doesn't work for your project, you might want to try making a data-request on [OpenData SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). Or try asking at [Earthscience SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) if such a map already exists.